# Hibernates add a new one when removing the facility

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In the controller I call a service method to remove "friendship" between users.

```
// Remove friendship
  friendshipService.removeFriendship(friendship);
```

This is the body of the method

```
@Override
public void removeFriendship(Friendship friendship) {
    Long fromId = friendship.getFromId();
    Long toId = friendship.getToId();

    friendshipRepository.delete(new Friendship(fromId, toId));
    friendshipRepository.delete(new Friendship(toId, fromId));
}
```

Unexpectedly, the Hibernate command with database looks like this

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into friendship (from_id, to_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from friendship where id=?
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into friendship (from_id, to_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from friendship where id=?
```

Why add new objects?

Comment: Show your `FriendshipRepository`. Also, if `Friendship` is just two id-s, I can smell that you are doing multiple things wrong. Relationships in Hibernate are not between id-s, they are between entities. Also, if it's such a simple relationship, it shouldn't be a separate entity, but rather a many-to-many between an entity class and itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of `new Friendship(...,...)`: you're telling to JPA to create new object and then delete it. As it is in a single transaction scope, JPA persists it as the new friendship is still managed. [A good SO question about managed vs unmanaged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7434115/4906586).

**Entity deletion**

Why don't you simply have

```
@Override
public void removeFriendship(Friendship friendship) {
    friendshipRepository.delete(friendship);
}
```

If friendship is linking two users, ensure that those users have their friend list `user.getFriendshipList();` updated

**JPA only deletes managed entities**

Beware about [your transaction scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428834/4906586) when deleting entities. I assume that behind `friendshipRepository.delete(Friendship friendship)`, you have something like `entityManager.remove(friendship);`

```
@Override
public void removeFriendship(Friendship friendship) {
    Friendship managedFriendship = entityManager.getReference(Friendship.class, friendship.getId());
    friendshipRepository.delete(managedFriendship);
}
```

---

*Friendship definition*

Unrelated to JPA deletion, I wonder why `Friendship(fromId, toId) != Friendship(toId, fromId)`. If friendship is a link between two users, the relation should be symetric